# Mac application how to add Store Kit

Tags: xcode, macos, in-app-purchase

My Xcode is 4.2. And I am not able to get Store kit in the build phase. and if i add manually taking the framework from the iOS folder I am getting error in framework itself. How can i add Storekit to my mac application for doing in App purchase in the application

Comment: Did you get any way to resolve the issue?I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In app purchase for Mac is only available for Lion version. for iOS devices we can add in app purchase in Leopard OS but for Mac we need to update to MAC OS X Lion